# AWS secret manger: how to keep empty space in the Secret value?

Tags: aws-secrets-manager

We use secrets in AWS Secrets Manager to store environment variable. It happens that we want to store cron job configuration there.

Tried this

Secret Key                  Secret value

MySpringScheduler           0 15 19 * * *

However, once our AWS application instance started, I got an error "Cron expression must consists of 6 fields (found 1 in "01519ap-0.0.1.......).  It seems that it removed all the spaces. Is there a way I can keep the space in the value?  I tried single quote like this '0 15 19 * * *' but it is not working.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using command line to retrieve secret and check if it is removing spaces?

If you created secret as 'Other type of Secret', it should store the key value as it is.

I tested your example and retrieved the value as it is.

```
aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id my/secret

{
    "ARN": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:120908898939}:secret:my/secret-4VBhSx",
    "Name": "my/secret",
    "VersionId": "4dd9e462-8748-4621-b388-2050a0d9de33",
    "SecretString": "{\"MySpringScheduler\":\"0 15 19 * * *\"}",
    "VersionStages": [
        "AWSCURRENT"
    ],
    "CreatedDate": "2022-07-07T21:47:30.110000-04:00"
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mahesh, I can only add /change the key/value in AWS Secrets manager screen and don't have any other access.  Basically,  I would like to retrieve that value and used for spring scheduler in a spring boot application.  like this: @Scheduled(cron="${MySpringScheduler})
public void notifyChange(){}     This works in my local environment

Comment: Try to the print the value and see if your java code is manipulating the secret value. If yes, then it is an issue with the code